# How to combine partitioned dataset to single dataset?

Tags: cross-validation, dataset, partitioning

I have been doing some Machine learning research on Microarray dataset. So, I downloaded breast cancer dataset from "http://datam.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/datasets/krbd/BreastCancer". The problem here is , this dataset is partioned to "test" and "Train" set. So I have few questions related to this.

1) Why do they want to partition the dataset to "Train" and "Test". Why can't they provide a single dataset file.
2) Is there any advantage on using partitioned dataset ?
3) How can I do crossvalidaton on Partioned dataset ?
4) If I want a single dataset file, Can I combine both "Test" and "Train" to single file and use it ? Does this make any problems ?

Any help on this regard will be greatly appreciated.
Also, I am new to Machine Learning field, Please excuse if there are any mistakes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Before initiating your ML research, you must question yourself. What kind of Learning it is? In case of supervised learning e.g. Classifying weather a certain medical record falls into certain pre-defined Class i.e. A: "ITS A Breast Cancer" or B: "Its not a breast cancer". In order to do that, an algorithm must be trained (supervised) with some records or experience. And this supervision is conducted with the Training data. And once, It is trained with that data(becomes a ML model), It is applied to the Test dataset to get predictions. In case of Unsupervised kind of learning, e.g. Clustering a group of students into some cluster based on some attributes similarity, e.g. marks, ages. The training part is skipped since ML model is not supervised with any training dataset. It can be applied to a whole dataset to get cluster centres. This Quora link would be helpful: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-supervised-and-unsupervised-learning-algorithms

Comment: Thanks for the information. But my question is not yet answered. It is not about the classification , my question is, if we get a partitioned dataset , can we combine them to single dataset and train some algorithm on that single dataset and  use the crossvalidation to measure the accuracy ? Does this approach make any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I will be using information from Manish's answer to answer your query

## 1) Why do they want to partition the dataset to "Train" and "Test". Why can't they provide a single dataset file.

Because they can ;-). The idea is you train your classifier on the training data and report your results on the test data. In these divisions test data is untouched and never used in training.

## 2) Is there any advantage on using partitioned dataset ?

Yes! As I said above this test data is never seen by training algorithm so it can be considered as a true generalisation error. This is similar to the concept of three-way split.

## 3) How can I do crossvalidaton on Partioned dataset ?

Take only the training dataset, run cross-validation to identify appropriate variables and parameters for the models (model selection). Then train a final model from all training dataset. Finally, use that model to predict on the test dataset. The prediction accuracy or any other metric that you use would resemble the true generalisation error of the system.

## 4) If I want a single dataset file, Can I combine both "Test" and "Train" to single file and use it ? Does this make any problems ?

Yes! You can combine them and run 10 fold cross-validation on them and if you are using some unsupervised algorithms (eg. clustering), it is good idea to do that. It doesn't create any problems but the process I described above in 3 is the accepted norm in reporting when datasets are already split into training and test sets.